# Hide select option field from contact form

Tags: forms, select, hide

I'm creating a template showcase theme that has a set of image blocks and i'm having a custom contact form too. As soon as users selects an image it'll dynamically select from my custom form's select option too.

Now i'm trying to hide my select option field,

My code is

```
<form action="">
    <select name="templates">
      <option value="THEME001">THEME001</option>
      <option value="THEME002">THEME002</option> 
      <option value="THEME003">THEME003</option> 
      <option value="THEME004">THEME004</option> 
      <option value="THEME005">THEME005</option>  
    </select>
</form>
```

So far i tried `type="hidden"` but its not working. Is there any other way to do it other than using ccs `visibility:hidden`

Comment: have u considered using Javascript / jQuery? Especially jQuery. It has a .hide() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function like

```
$("select").hide();
```

I think you can remove it by Jquery's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

```
$("select").remove();
```

Just pick the select element and you can use these Jquery functions to hide or remove your select element

With javascript you have to use like the following (display = 'none')

```
document.getElementById('THE ID OF YOUR SELECT BOX').style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: ,. Thanks for your reply. I followed your method. All i'm getting is a blank space at the place of **selected template field** in my email. I need to pass option value.